# What are advantages and disadvantages of abstracting our database behind stored procedures?

Tags: sql, api, postgresql, database-design

At work we currently have a PostgreSQL database and we access it via some Perl bindings to access the database and marshal responses to Perl types. This works OK, but for various reasons we are becoming unhappy with Perl. One option we've been considering is to move the majority of the work in this API to the database itself as `plpgsql` stored  procedures.

## Brief Example

For example, we might have the following in the database:

```
-- This matches our 'Entity::Artist' object
CREATE TYPE loaded_artist (
  artist_id uuid,
  revision_id integer,
  artist_tree_id integer,
  name text,
  sort_name text,
  artist_type_id integer,
  -- etc
);

-- This gets the latest 'master' version of an artist and joins in basic data
-- from the artist tree
CREATE FUNCTION get_latest_artist_by_mbid(in_mbid UUID)
RETURNS SETOF loaded_artist AS $$
  BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT
      artist_id, revision_id, artist_tree_id, name.name,
      sort_name.name AS sort_name, artist_type_id
    FROM artist
    JOIN artist_revision USING (artist_id)
    JOIN artist_tree USING (artist_tree_id)
    JOIN artist_data USING (artist_data_id)
    WHERE artist.master_revision_id = revision_id
      AND artist_id = in_mbid;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Now our current Perl API can be simplified to effectively the following:# And in Perl

```
package Data::Artist;
sub get_latest_by_mbid {
    my ($self, $mbid) = @_;
    return $self->new_from_row(
        $self->sql->select_single_row_hash(
            'SELECT * FROM get_latest_artist_by_mbid(?)',
            $mbid));
}
```

## Is this sensible?

On face value, I like this. We:

- Move away from Perl, but don't commit to another language. This means we can move our actual application to Python/whatever in the future and the majority of our API is already done.
- Get extra type safety from PostgreSQL due to specifying things like `RETURNS SETOF loaded_artist`
- Still have unit tests and stuff via PGTAP.

There are a few disadvantages:

- Potentially lower development cycle as we now have to replace functions in the database. Not the end of the world, but this effectively introduces a 'compile' step into our workflow that was not previously there.
- Potentially more difficult version control, but there are certainly ways of doing it

Has anyone done work like this? Would you encourage it, or was it fraught with peril?

---

## Footnote: A little more about our case

This is for an open source website. We distribute dumps of our database for people to import into PostgreSQL databases. We have no plans to move away from PG any time soon, so database agnostic decisions don't really apply to us. We are a very small team (2 paid developers, more open source contributors) and this lets us be quite flexible in terms of deployment strategies.

Comment: "but there are certainly ways of doing it" --- not even close to what we have for regular code

Comment: This might be interesting: http://ledgersmbdev.blogspot.de/2011/11/case-for-intelligent-databases.html  Regarding version control: have a look at Liquibase or Flyway for schema versioning/migration.

Comment: Sqitch might also be an option for version control: http://www.slideshare.net/justatheory/sqitch-pgconsimple-sql-change-management-with-sqitch  and https://github.com/theory/sqitch/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Advantages:

- database schema / layout / storage changes are completely hidden from the application;
- you have a unified API to work with the database;
- you can have extensive logging on all actions done in the database, including all `SELECT` queries.

Disadvantages:

- increased need in the good DBAs;
- increased need in the database developers with good understanding of how database is working with data and how DB-side procedures work;
- more coordination will be required between DB-side and Application-side teams;
- difficulties with ORM integration;
- using stored procedures limits optimization possibilities of the database and some queries (especially reports) will be giving performance issues, it is better to use views instead, as optimizer can push down predicates into the view and utilize indexes properly.

Best combination is when you implement a deal of your business logic on the database side and not only wrapper functions.

Schema version control is possible. It is more tricky to version the data in the configuration tables. In one of the project I'm involved this is done via the external tool (perl based) that handles this part for us:

- data is loaded / extracted into intermediate tables first;
- then it is analyzed for RI constraints and all possible violations;
- data manipulations are possible before loading it into live tables;
- business objects that spawns multiple tables can be defined and extracted in one go;
- several ways of treating matching entities exists, like: overwrite, merge, duplicate.

We're versioning the extract files instead (which a plain SQL) and have a special step in the installation script to load the new configuration.

Comment: One downside of a stored-proc approach is that it won't work wonderfully with most ORMs. You'll be coding more directly against the database. That may bring significant performance benefits though, as developers who're hiding the DB behind an ORM often struggle to make the ORM behave sanely and efficiently.

Comment: Stored proc based interfaces are also often a PITA when you're working with windowed/paginated data and can be very inefficient for generalised filters. The DB can't push `WHERE` conditions or `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` down into the query/queries executed by the proc, so it may land up fetching *lots* more data than it needs to and throwing it away. Using plain `SQL` stored procs where possible helps with this as Pg can inline non-immutable SQL stored procs but not PL/PgSQL ones. The flipside is that your stored procs can be optimised w/o changing app code, so can often be lots faster...

Comment: In one example from a couple of days ago, I converted a stored procedure I was querying to a view and saw queries with quite specific `WHERE` clauses become more than 100x times faster because the DB could push the filter conditions down into the view's query. It could also plan the query as a whole faster, so even an unfiltered use sped up by 25%. The lesson here: Be prepared to swap your procs for views where practical and safe to do so.

Comment: @CraigRinger, API-based interfaces tend to work in the OLTP-like mode, i.e. provide access to the individual objects in your set. Otherwise you comment is completely valid, one should be careful using stored procedures for the reporting or other similar subset of queries.

Comment: @CraigRinger the ORM part is not a problem, as we have our own in house access layer. The paging stuff is indeed problematic, and in my prototypes so far I've just pushed offset/limit as parameters to the stored procedure itself.

Answer (score 0):

To the point of portability:

- By using stored procedures, you are more portable on the client, as you already noted.
- By **not** using stored procedures, you are more portable on the server (you can more easily move to a different DBMS).

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this, I've added a footnote to my question outlining our actual use case. Portability to the server is not something we are concerned about as we are happily staying with PG for at least the next few years, and I would imagine longer.

Comment: @ocharles Sure, it all depends on the circumstances. In my case, almost all of our projects need to be portable to multiple DBMSes, so we tend to avoid stored procedures for that reason. If you know you'll stay with the same DBMS for a long time, then it makes sense to centralize as much logic as you can in the stored procedures.

Comment: This point crops up every time this topic is discussed but people very rarely draw the right conclusion.  Organisations very rarely change their choice of application database: if you start with Oracle you'll almost certainly stick with it (ISVs are the notable excpetion here).  On the other hand front end technologies are in a constant state of flux.

Comment: The other thing is, PL/SQL is close to becoming an industry standard.  PostgreSQL supports it and now so does DB2 (but perhaps not perfectly).  And since Oracle now own MySQL it wouldn't surprise me if they ported PL/SQL to that database as well.  Which would leave SQL Server as the only major RDBMS with a proprietary stored propcedure language.

Comment: @APC As you said, ISVs are a notable exception - it is not always about a single organisation and its DBMS, it can also be about a single codebase working in many organisations, with different DBMSes.

Comment: @APC: PostgreSQL does not support PL/SQL. The Entreprise DB [closed-source fork](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/products/postgres-plus-advanced-server/advanced-server-oracle-features) tries to, as much as possible. As for standards, PostgreSQL is more likely to implement [SQL/PSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL/PSM) in the future than Oracle's PL/SQL.

Comment: @DanielVérité - okay "support" is a bit strong (a bit wrong) but PL/pgSQL is pretty similar to PL/SQL.